# The set of points of a sequence cannot form any other thing than a subsequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $x_n$ be a sequence and let $X=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_i,\ldots\}$ be the set of points of $x_n$. The intuition tells me that if I create any sequence of elements of $X$ (By which I mean taking $x_i$ in any order, not necessarily increasing the index), then it is indeed a subsequence of $x_n$, at least since certain $n$ onwards. I would like to know if this intuition is true and if it is, how is this supposed to be proved? Thanks.

Comment: By definition, the elements of a subsequence must be in the same order as they are in the original sequence.

Comment: @Adam: True, but not relevant, since the OP is asking only that the new sequence be in the right order **from some point on**.

Comment: Even if the sequence is in the right order from some point on, it's not a subsequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true: consider the sequence

$$\langle x_2,x_1,x_4,x_3,x_6,x_5,\ldots\rangle\;,$$

formed by reversing the order of each pair $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n-1}$. No matter where you start, no tail of this is a subsequence of the original sequence.

**Added:** The most that you can guarantee is that your subsequence has an infinite subsequence that is also a subsequence of the old sequence. This is because if your subsequence is $\langle x_{\sigma(n)}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, then the sequence $\langle\sigma(n):n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ always has an infinite strictly increasing subsequence.

Comment: I was going to post this exact example but figured I'd be beaten. Note that your sequence *shares* a subsequence with the original, and I think this is always true.

Comment: @pjs36: Yes, it is: every infinite sequence of positive integers has a strictly increasing subsequence.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. I like that the OP asked the question (doesn't feel like a homework question) and thought it would be nice to say "Not quite, but a similar statement is true."

Comment: @pjs36: I’m inclined to agree and have added such a comment to my answer.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what’s wrong?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott About your last remark on the increasing subsequence, is it related with the demonstration that every infinite subset X of N is countable(Defining f(1)=least element of X, and f(n)= least element of X-{f(1),...,f(n-1)}, defining an increasing bijection ?)

Comment: @user301198: Very similar in concept, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Not, it doesn't. Remember that $\{y_n\}$ is a subsequence of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ if there is an injective function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $y_n=x_{f(n)}$.

Thus, if take, say, $f(n)=1$, then $f$ is not injective, but $y_n=x_{f(n)}=x_1$ for all $n$ satisfies your hypothesis and isn't a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ by defintion.